# foreach in foreach c#

Tags: c#, foreach

query: 0 4 1 0 0

secQuery: 1 1 0 0 3

I need to compare elements: 0 and 1, 4 and 1 , 1 and 0 ,0 and 0 , 0 and 3.
But break stops my second foreach.

I try this:

```
foreach (var a in query)
{
    bool flag = false;
    foreach (var b in secQuery)
    {
        if (b > a)
        {
            count++;
        }
        flag = true;
        break;
    }
    if (flag) continue;
}
```

And this:

```
foreach (var a in query)
{
    foreach (var b in secQuery)
    {
        if (b > a)
        {
           count++;
        }
     //break; continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code snippet shown will compare each element in the first list with every element in the second one. Is it OK?

Comment: Why not use one `for`that iterates over the minimum of the lengths of each array? Seems like you want to do something like `for(int i=0; i < Math.Min(query.Count, secQuery.Count); i++) if(query[i] > secQuery[i]) count++;` Right now you're comparing every element of `query` with every other element of `secQuery`, complexity is n². Preciecly define your problem first. I don't understand why you'd want to immediatly `break` in the inner `foreach` loop after the first iteration and then also break the outer one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need a nested loop for comparing parallel arrays. You need a single loop that iterates both arrays at the same time - for example, by their index:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i != query.Length ; i++) {
    var first = query[i];
    var second = secQuery[i];
    Console.WriteLine("Comparing {0} and {1}", first, second);
}
```

The above code assumes that both arrays have the same number of elements.

You can also pair up elements using LINQ's `Zip` method:

```
foreach (var p in query.Zip(secQuery, (first, second) => new {first, second}) {
    Console.WriteLine("Comparing {0} and {1}", p.first, p.second);        
}
```

If all you need is the count of items in `query` that are greater than `secQuery`, compute it like this:

```
var res = query
    .Zip(secQuery, (first, second) => first > second)
    .Count(cmp => cmp);
```

Comment: I had originally thought of zip; in this case, the OP just wants a comparison count and I couldn't think of a decent way of using zip to return the comparison count. I'd be interested if you had some ideas.

Comment: @MetroSmurf You could combine them into a `bool`, and count how many items are `true` (see edit).

Comment: Interesting approach to project into a bool and count against the true items. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to zipping or a standard for loop is to use the overload in [Linq.Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx) that provides access to the index of the element being evaluated and use the index to compare to the other list:

```
var q1 = new[] {0, 4, 1, 0, 0};

var q2 = new[] {1, 1, 0, 0, 3};

int count = q1.Where( (x,i) => q2[i] > x ).Count();
```

The result of `count` will be 2.

Answer (score 0):

You code now shows how to compare an element `a` from the first list with each element `b` of the second list.

What you are saying you want to do is actually compare respective elements to each other. Use simply an indexer.

```
if(query.Count() == secQuery.Count()) {
    for(var i = 0; i<query.Count(); i++) {
        var a = query[i]; //assuming you have an indexer on your types, otherwise maybe you can convert to List using ToList() linq method
        var b = secQuery[i];
        if(b > a) count++; //now a and b are corresponding elements you can compare them
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The task is not clearly defined, so based on the qualified guess, it seems that you can achieve the result in a rather simple way using *for-loop*:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= query.Length; i++)
{
    if(query[i]<secQuery[i]) count++
}
```

Hope this may help.